# "Come and sit on the bed along with us", is it correct?

Tags: prepositions

We were sitting on the bed and were eating something while my son was about to sit on the floor.

I told my son:

> Come and sit on the bed along with us

My question is, is it the right way to ask him to come and sit beside us and start eating?

Comment: The title of your question says ***come and sit on the bed along with us***. But the body of your question says ***join us on the bed by sitting beside us***. Those are completely different constructions. Which one are you asking about? Also, neither one of them mentions anything about starting to eat. (And if that's essential, both sentences are immediately wrong for not providing that detail.) Please clarify the exact sentence you are asking about—and if eating needs to be part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Although I believe this is technically correct, it would be more common to drop the "along".

If you do want to clarify you can use the word *alongside*:

> [**Alongside**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alongside) - next to, or together with (UK); beside, or together with (US)

My reason for this slight change is because of the definition of [*along*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/along) which isn't as clear, but one of the the many definitions is:

> **along** - with you

Note: this link also backs up my initial sentiment that it is not technically wrong with the example:

> Why don't you take him along with you when you go?